# get object from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, angular

i have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
invitations: Array<record> = [new record()];

    interface recordMap {
     value:string;
     err:string
   }

export class record{
  number: recordMap ;
  deptNumber: recordMap ;
  boothNumber: recordMap ;
  primaryEmail: recordMap ;
  members: recordMap [];
}
```

my backend request body has to look like this

```
[
  {
    "number": "string",
    "deptNumber": 0,
    "boothNumber": "string",
    "primaryEmail": "string",
    "members": [
      "string"
    ]
  }
]
```

this is what i have tried so far
my struggle is for the members property because it is an array in the invitation array and I am trying to get only the value from it and push it to the request body array members.

the result of my code is code 400 bad request.
How can i make this object?

```
const invitationArray = [];
    this.invitations.forEach(invitation => {
      invitationArray.push({
        number: invitation.number.value,
        deptNumber: invitation.deptNumber.value,
        boothNumber: invitation.boothNumber.value,
        primaryEmail: invitation.primaryEmail.value,
        members: invitation.members.forEach(number => number.value)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. From the docs:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of
>   calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
var members = [{ value: 'value1', error: 'error1' }, { value: 'value2', error: 'error2' }, { value: 'value3', error: 'error3' }, { value: 'value4', error: 'error4' }]

console.log(members.map(member => member.value));
```

Try the following

```js
const invitationArray = [];
    this.invitations.forEach(invitation => {
      invitationArray.push({
        number: invitation.number.value,
        deptNumber: Number(invitation.deptNumber.value),
        boothNumber: invitation.boothNumber.value,
        primaryEmail: invitation.primaryEmail.value,
        members: invitation.members.map(member => member.value)
  });
});
```

Also it appears `deptNumber` property is expected to be of type `number`. I've converted it to number as well.